# How to make RecyclerView with a Divider

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to make a RecyclerView with a divider?

My RecyclerView looks like this.

[image]

And I want to achieve a RecyclerView that looks like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

item_row XML:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"  >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rvname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.luminous.pick.FlipActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add please xml files of your layout

Comment: @piotrek1543 I updated my post.

Comment: Just remove this line `android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"` from your row item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your recycler view looks like that because your recyclerview_item.xml have CardView in it. So just delete them.

**ANSWER UPDATE:**

To create item diver you should do the following

Create DividerItemDecoration Class

```
public class DividerItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {


private static final int[] ATTRS = new int[]{
        android.R.attr.listDivider
};

public static final int HORIZONTAL_LIST = LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL;

public static final int VERTICAL_LIST = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL;

private Drawable mDivider;

private int mOrientation;

public DividerItemDecoration(Context context, int orientation) {
    final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(ATTRS);
    mDivider = a.getDrawable(0);
    a.recycle();
    setOrientation(orientation);
}

public void setOrientation(int orientation) {
    if (orientation != HORIZONTAL_LIST && orientation != VERTICAL_LIST) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid orientation");
    }
    mOrientation = orientation;
}

@Override
public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {

    if (mOrientation == VERTICAL_LIST) {
        drawVertical(c, parent);
    } else {
        drawHorizontal(c, parent);
    }
}

public void drawVertical(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
    final int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
    final int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

    final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);

        final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child
                .getLayoutParams();
        final int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
        final int bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right,bottom);

        mDivider.draw(c);
    }
}

public void drawHorizontal(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
    final int top = parent.getPaddingTop();
    final int bottom = parent.getHeight() - parent.getPaddingBottom();

    final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        Log.i("LOH", "drawHorizontal: "+ parent.getChildViewHolder(child).getItemViewType());
        final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child
                .getLayoutParams();
        final int left = child.getRight() + params.rightMargin;
        final int right = left + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        mDivider.draw(c);
    }
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (mOrientation == VERTICAL_LIST) {
        outRect.set(0, 0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight());
    } else {
        outRect.set(0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0);
    }
}}
```

In fragment/activity with RecyclerView do the following:

```
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
```

Comment: It works, but how can I add a divider between two recyclerview??

Comment: @ChristineRamos you mean between recycler view items?

Comment: Yes. I updated the image above.

Comment: @ChristineRamos check

Comment: @AntonKazavok my activity says 'Cannot resolve getActivity()'

Comment: @ChristineRamos change it to  - this. getActivity is used in fragments

Comment: @AntonKazavok Sorry for the late response. Thank you the code works.

Comment: @ChristineRamos no problem:) If this answer helped you up vote pls